# How to update the string with priority order in the dictionary

Tags: python

I have list of dict below

```
data = 
[ { 'Pencil': 'Green' }, { 'Pen': 'N/A' }, { 'Scale': 'Red' }, { 'Compass': 'N/A'}]
```

My priority order is below

```
priority_order = {'Red':4, 'Orange':3, 'Yellow':2, 'Green':1, 'Undefined': 0}
```

I have main variable which has to update with in priority order of values in `data` list of dictionary, by default main is

```
main = 'Undefined'
```

Code is below

```
for each in data:
    for k,v in each.items():
        if priority_order[v] > priority_order[main]:
            main = priority_order[v]
```

I am getting key error for this

My expected out is 'Red' as  `scale` is having 'Red'

Comment: What do you expect `priority_order["N\A"]` to be?

Comment: i tried with if v in priority_order: also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data =[ { 'Pencil': 'Green' }, { 'Pen': 'N/A' }, { 'Scale': 'Red' }, { 'Compass': 'N/A'}]
priority_order = {'Red':4, 'Orange':3, 'Yellow':2, 'Green':1, 'N/A': 0}
main = 'N/A'

for each in data:
    for k,v in each.items():
        if priority_order[v] > priority_order[main]:
            main = v
print(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for each in data:
    for k, v in each.items():
        if v in priority_order:
            if priority_order[v] > priority_order[main]:
                main = v
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: same error i got KeyError: 1

Comment: @sim my bad, shoud be ok now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `max()` call:

```
data =[ { 'Pencil': 'Green' }, { 'Pen': 'N/A' }, { 'Scale': 'Red' }, { 'Compass': 'N/A'}]
priority_order = {'Red':4, 'Orange':3, 'Yellow':2, 'Green':1, 'N/A': 0}

print(max((v for each in data for v in each.values()), key=priority_order.get))
```

prints:

```
Red
```

If you want it to be able to handle values that aren't in `priority_order`, specify a `key` that supplies a default priority (since the default `None` will raise a `TypeError` on comparisons with ints):

```
print(max(
    (v for each in data for v in each.values()),
    key=lambda v: priority_order.get(v, 0)
))
```